# gravity forms append value to $activate_url

Tags: forms

How can I add a field value to the end of the `$activate_url` that's sent in the activation email? 
Such as `$activate_url . ?key=$key**&as=$fieldvalue**`,  I don't know enough about GForm to pass these values.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two examples. This first one is the barebones version:

```
/**
 * Gravity Wiz // GF User Registration // Modify Activation URL
 */
add_filter( 'wpmu_signup_user_notification_email', 'gw_modify_activation_url', 11, 4 );
function gw_modify_activation_url( $message, $username, $email, $key ) {

    // find the current activation URL in the message
    if ( is_callable( 'bp_get_activation_page' ) ) {
        $search = esc_url_raw( sprintf( '%s?key=%s', bp_get_activation_page(), $key ) );
    } else {
        $search = esc_url_raw( add_query_arg( array( 'page' => 'gf_activation', 'key' => $key ), get_site_url() . '/' ) );
    }

    // add your query parameters to the current activation URL
    $replace = add_query_arg( array( 'my_key' => 'my_value' ), $search );

    // replace the current activation URL with the updated URL
    $message = str_replace( $search, $replace, $message );

    return $message;
}
```

And this version beefs it up with support for accessing the $entry object associated with the activation key so you can include data from the entry in the modified activation URL.

```
/**
 * Gravity Wiz // GF User Registration // Modify Activation URL w/ Entry Data
 */
add_filter( 'wpmu_signup_user_notification_email', 'gw_modify_activation_url_with_entry_data', 11, 4 );
function gw_modify_activation_url_with_entry_data( $message, $username, $email, $key ) {

    // make sure GF User Registration is loaded
    if( ! is_callable( array( 'GFUser', 'get_base_path' ) ) ) {
        return $mesage;
    }

    // include the signups functionality
    require_once( GFUser::get_base_path() . '/includes/signups.php' );

    // get the signup object for the provided key, this contains all the GF related information you'll ever want for the key
    $signup = GFSignup::get( $key );
    if( is_wp_error( $signup ) ) {
        return $message;
    }

    // set the "lead" property of the signup to an $entry variable for clarity
    // "lead" is no longer the correct term for the data associated with a GF submission
    $entry = $signup->lead;

    // find the current activation URL in the message
    if ( is_callable( 'bp_get_activation_page' ) ) {
        $search = esc_url_raw( sprintf( '%s?key=%s', bp_get_activation_page(), $key ) );
    } else {
        $search = esc_url_raw( add_query_arg( array( 'page' => 'gf_activation', 'key' => $key ), get_site_url() . '/' ) );
    }

    // add your query parameters to the current activation URL
    $replace = add_query_arg( array( 'my_key' => $entry[1] ), $search );

    // replace the current activation URL with the updated URL
    $message = str_replace( $search, $replace, $message );

    return $message;
}
```

If you need to actually modify the activation template based on the query string, see this article: http://gravitywiz.com/customizing-gravity-forms-user-registration-activation-page/

Comment: thanks so much, David - appreciate the time you took to put that together. I figured it out yesterday, but i can surely learn much more from your code and comments. i'm not versed in WP hooks, but i'm starting to see that i'm gonna need to be. thanks again